What is my reasoning error when solving this compound inequality using floor bounds?
I'm looking to solve the compound inequality $$(2/3)^hn \lt n_0 \le (2/3)^{h-1}n$$ for the integer h, with $0 \lt n_0 \le n$.
Context
$h$ represents the height of the recursion-tree of a divide-and-conquer algorithm whose running time is characterized by the recurrence $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + \Theta(n)$ in "Introduction to Algorithms"  (4th edition) by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein, page 99.
The authors directly state that $h = \lfloor \log_{3/2}(n/n_0) \rfloor + 1$ since we can apply the floor bounds $x-1 \lt \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ with $x = \log_{3/2}(n/n_0)$ to show that
$$
\begin{align}
(2/3)^hn &= (2/3)^{\lfloor x \rfloor + 1} \\
&\lt (2/3)^xn \\
&= (2/3)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)}n \\
&= (n_0/n)n \\
&= n_0
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
(2/3)^{h-1}n &= (2/3)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}n \\
&\ge (2/3)^xn \\
&= (2/3)^{\log_{3/2}(n/n_0)}n \\
&= (n_0/n)n \\
&= n_0
\end{align}
$$
which verify that $(2/3)^hn \lt n_0 \le (2/3)^{h-1}n$.
What I've tried
I was wondering how they make such a guess and I tried to find it starting from the inequality:
$$
\begin{align}
&(2/3)^hn &&\lt n_0 &&\le (2/3)^{h-1}n &\\
&(2/3)^h &&\lt n_0/n &&\le (2/3)^{h-1} &\text{(since $n \gt 0$)}\\
&(3/2)^{h-1} &&\le n/n_0 &&\lt (3/2)^h &\\
&h-1 &&\le \log_{3/2}(n/n_0) &&\lt h &\\
&h &&\le \log_{3/2}(n/n_0)+1 &&\lt h+1
\end{align}
$$
Unexpectedly, it looks more like the ceil bounds ($x \le \lceil x \rceil \lt x+1$) than the the floor bounds ($x-1 \lt \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$). What am I missing here ?

Your derivation is correct. What seems to confuse you is that you are getting an inequality of the type
$$i \le r < i+1,$$
(where $i$ stands for an integer and $r$ for a real number) and comparing it to an inequality of the type
$$r-1 < i \le r.$$
Both inequalities describe the same relationship, but the former puts the real number in the center and the latter the integer. They are different forms to 'define' the floor function.
Note that $i \le r$ is part of both of inequalities. They just use different methods to make sure that $i$ is the largest integer fulfilling that condition.
